# Submission of programatically added fields in webforms

Tags: webforms, 10

I have an ever-increasing set of hidden fields that should be added to every form in my site.
I created helper update-hook functions to add new fields to the form, but now forms have too many fields and editing becomes cumbersome, so I tried adding the fields through a webform_submission_form_alter hook.

The fields are added an can be seen on the rendered HTML with:

```
$form['elements'][$field_name] = [
  '#type' => 'hidden',
];
```

but the value of this field is never available on the webform_submission data.
I have also tried copying the exact same array keys as a standard hidden field, but it didn't help.

My goal is to have this field value sent through a remote_post handler, possibly renaming it on custom data with a token like **[webform_submission:values:field]**.

I'm using Drupal 10, webform version 6.2.0.
Is there a way to do this?